# Are professional sports players liable for an opponent's injury?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torts-damages, mishpatim, injury

[Shemot 21:18-19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=352) discusses the procedure of payment when one person injures another.

Does, say, a professional boxer have to pay his opponent if he injures him during a boxing match? Are the rules different, here, because professionals enter the competition understanding that there is a direct risk of injury?

(My question can be applied to any professional sport using the same scenario. E.g. a tennis player smacks the ball and hits his opponent in the eye.)